# Jasper report generate table with null values

Tags: jasper-reports

I create a template of report in Jasper Studio. I need to fill table from dataset.

I added to template a table and trying to add values with datasetRun:

```
<datasetRun subDataset="tableData" uuid="9180ffca-a5b5-4f4c-bbf8-656f3be735eb">                          
   <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource() ]]> 
   </dataSourceExpression>
</datasetRun>
```

When I creating a table, I added all field from my dataset

Now, when I creating a report, I getting null values in table.

How to fix it?

I know that I can get values from a parametr in dataset, but I don't understood how to create this parametr correctly

Comment: You are passing an empty datasource what do you expect to get?

Comment: @PetterFriberg what I should passing to get fields from dataset?

Comment: A datasoruce or a Database connection that contains those fields

Comment: @PetterFriberg I don't find class in documentation which should connect to dataset's fields. Can you write class which I should to use?

Comment: Are you sure you need to write a class?, are you connecting to a database?, maybe it's enough you pass the connecting and define the query (sql)

Comment: @PetterFriberg I get data from JSON. In JSON I have data for header of report, and array of objects with data for table. Fields for header I add to main fields, data from array I added to dataset

Comment: ok, so search for [that](https://www.google.com/search?q=jasper+report+json+example&oq=jasper+report+json+example&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.5966j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), you need to create a datasource from your json